# When writing junit test cases, which one of the following is best to use for empty list?

Tags: string, arraylist, collections, junit, empty-list

When writing junit test cases, which one of the following is best to use for empty list ?

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

OR

```
Collections.<String> emptyList();
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever possible I prefer `Collections.emptyList()` over the `ArrayList`, because this ensures that the main code doesn’t try to modify the given list, which in most cases is the correct behavior.

In practice I use Guava’s `ImmutableList`, since that covers not only empty lists but also nonempty ones.